# Tidy way of migrating data between tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, entity-framework

Is there a way of using EF and/or C# code to migrate data to a new table (and entity), or would I have to use some plain old-fashioned SQL in my EF-Migration?

Here's my situation:

I have an existing `OldCarLog` class that as used to log user actions on an entity we'll call `Car`, but now I want to allow logging on other entities and I've created an abstract/generic class `BrandSpankingNewActivityLog<TEntity>` to make logging of any class easy. So I have `Car_Log : BrandSpankingNewActivityLog<Car>` along with `PartInfo_Log` and `RepairProcedure_Log`.

I want to take all the `OldCarLog` entities and convert them into their replacement `Car_Log` 
this way I can refactor the `OldCarLog` into `Car_Log` and have a standard API for the newly implemented logs without having `OldCarLog` get confused with any logs derived from `BrandSpankingNewActivityLog<TEntity>`.

```
public abstract class BrandSpankingNewActivityLog<TEntity>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivityTime { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual TEntity Entity { get; set; }
}

public class Car_Log : BrandSpankingNewActivityLog<Car>
{
    //Nothing to see here!
}

public class Car
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    //Other car info you don't care about ....
    //Yada, Yada, Yada....
    public virtual ICollection<Car_Logs> {get;set;}
}
```

Does that all make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In the `DbMigration::Up()` make a call using the `SQL("TODO: Add SQL");` method.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql(v=vs.113).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: I've done this before, I was just hoping to avoid doing it again, it'd just be nicer to use some C# logic/classes/type-safety instead of using my less reliable SQL.